# Javascript: TypeError confusion

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm learning Javascript, and found this frustrating to understand.

Below are two functions that compute the sum of integers in a given array with one working solution and the other one working *partially*.

Here is my working function:

```
 var sum = function(array) {
        total = 0
        for (index in array) {
          total += array[index]
        }
        return total
    }
```

Here is the *partially working* function:

```
 var sum = function(array) {
        sum = 0
        for (index in array) {
          sum += array[index]
        }
        return sum
    }
```

You'll see that the point of difference is the **variable name**. I think I'm missing some fundamental understanding here, and would like some clarification.

Here are my test statements:

```
console.log(sum( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7] ) === 27)
console.log(sum( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7] ) === 27)
```

They are identical *on purpose* to show you the center of the issue.

For the working function, it returns true for *both* test statements.
For the partially working function, it returns true *once* followed by a `TypeError: number is not a function`

What is going on here?

Comment: Revenge of the missing `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sum = function(array) {
    var sum = 0; // Declare with var
    for (index in array) {
      sum += array[index];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

...will work. Just referencing `sum` causes the engine to look for a variable called `sum` firstly inside the function, and if not found there, it will traverse up the object's scope chain to find it. Declaring with `var` inside a function tells the engine that this is a new variable with its scope restricted to the direct parent object, in this case, the function.

Comment: This is a great explanation. But I'm still wondering why it printed out true for the first test statement if it was understood that `sum` is now a `number`?

Comment: @Lambin `sum` isn't a `number` the entire time. Initially, it is a `function`, so you can call it once. But, during that 1st invocation, the `function` is being replaced with the `number`.

Comment: "look up through the parent objects" should really be "looks for a variable called *sum* in the function, then on its scope chain".

Answer (score 2):

```
 var sum = function(array) {
    sum = 0
```

`sum` is now a number, not a function.

Comment: if that's true then why did the test statement print out true for the first test statement without raising an error?

Comment: @Lambin: Because you didn't assign it to a number yet.

Comment: @Lambin—because the second assignment to *sum* doesn't happen until the function is called and the assignment is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `sum` variable...

```
var sum = function(array) {
        sum = 0 // <-- doh!
        for (index in array) {
          sum += array[index]
        }
        return sum
    }
```

Make it clear to the interpreter that your inner variable is local... or give it a unique name, which also prevents confusion.

```
var sum = function(array) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (index in array) {
      sum += array[index];
    }
    return sum;
}
```